# Transport model's data from views to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model

In an Mvc3 project I have a model class which has a field name InsertDate. I don't want any control on the view for this field.

When data is being saved, it is comed as null and I set it as DateTime.Now on the controller side.

the problem is that: In the update view, this value comes to me null. I want this field to be set its default value in the update view.

Has anyone got an idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hidden field to store this data and then it will returns to you.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.InsertDate)
```

Comment: Actually I'm looking for another way. but bacuse of I got negative vote, I will accept this answer and run away. behaviours such this are make users demotivated. thanks for your response.

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? On the GET request your are retrieving the model from DB and put all data in the html elements. On the update you will submit the form and gather data from the form. So you have 2 options: 1st - get the data from DB and update fields, 2nd - use some html element to deliver it for you in the POST.

Comment: Now I already use 2nd way. But I think that: may be I have many field which I don't what them to be shown on the UI. Then, i should look for another way. But I guess you wrote all two ways. no problem then, I'll use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate view model for each view. Your update view simply excludes that field and sets it uponbupdatkng your model that will go to the database. Use the free tool automapper to copy fields between those models.